# Item Not Supported: Error not Going Away

Tags: zabbix

I am using Zabbix 3.2 for over 100 VMs (Windows, Linux, Mac) and I added a script to all of the Windows VMs. The script is local to every VM and agentd.conf has:

```
UserParameter=var,C:\path\to\script.bat
```

It also has a few other UserParameters, although that is not a part of this issue.

When I go to Items, the red "i" is present, status is "Not Supported", and hovering over the red "i" says:

> Received value [No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept] is not suitable for value type [Numeric (unsigned)] and data type [Decimal].

I find this very weird as it is local to watch VM and not using RDP. I was trying to use a share folder and have the script in 1 location. That obviously did not work which is why I am doing it locally.

The log says "old_random_var is not supported". This is another parameter that is working on zabbix, but is giving this log. Once again, this old_var is completely unrelated to var.

Using zabbix_get says that item is unsupported.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

E: Interesting addition, from all the nodes, it works in about 20 random ones, not the others. There is NOTHING unique about these nodes. Completely random.

Comment: Your script resides locally on all of those systems? What does the script do?

Comment: It checks for a ftp connection. Echos 1 or 0 if the connection exists or not.

Comment: And they are all checking the same FTP endpoint, right? Sounds like you are overloading that FTP server then.

Comment: Yes they are.. What could be a solution to this?

Comment: ftp server (Windows 2007 server) says ftp number of connections is at max

Answer (score 0):

Userparameter is connecting to Windows FTP. Connection limit must be increased on the Windows side.

Comment: I already went to the IIS Manager, went to Default Web Site, Advanced Settings and Connection Limits. Max connections at large value (unlimited)

Comment: There's nothing that can be done on the Zabbix side - if the remote side refuses the connection, that's it. You might benefit from making those items be queried less frequently.